# GridView.SelectedIndexChanged doesn't fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hello i have a gridview that is connected to the event selectedindexchanged and is on a hidden panel but when i try to fire the event don't do anything. 
This is the code of the gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="mGrid" 
                    Width="847px" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged2">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:ButtonField Text="Borrar" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

This is the code on the event:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    Response.Write(row.Cells[2].Text);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because that button isn't a `SelectButton`, one approach would be to set the `AutoGeneratesSelectButton` property on the `GridView` to `true`. You could then get rid of that other button you're trying to make work.

If you need that other button then you'll need to make it a `CommandField` and set the `ShowSelectButton` to true. With that configuration you can set the `SelectText` and have some custom text for the button.

Either way, a `Button` isn't going to do anything for `SelectedIndexChanged`.